# Generating a pre-signed URL for S3 object with KMS encryption - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I'm using the AWS SDK v2.3.44.0 for .NET 4.0 and am trying to generate a pre-signed URL for clients to download objects. All of the objects are stored in an S3 bucket and encrypted using the `aws:kms` server side encryption method.

I'm using the `AmazonS3Client`'s `GetPreSignedURL` method to generate the URL.

My `AmazonS3Client` object is created like so:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(new AmazonS3Config
{
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
    SignatureVersion = "4"
});
```

My `GetPresignedUrlRequest` object is created like so:

```
var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = bucket,
    Key = key,
    Expires = expires,
    ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AWSKMS
 };
```

Now when I run `client.GetPreSignedURL(request)` it generates a URL like so (formatted for readability and sanitized):

```
https://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}?AWSAccessKeyId={access key}
    &Expires={timestamp}
    &Signature=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256%20Credential%3D{access key}%2F20150626%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request%2C%20SignedHeaders%3Dhost%3Bx-amz-content-sha256%3Bx-amz-date%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption%2C%20Signature%3D{signature}
```

When navigating to this URL, I get an XML breakdown of an error: `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

This URL looks different from the one Amazon describes in [their docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html). Also, generating the URL from Visual Studio using the AWS plugin generates a **working** URL that looks like this (again formatted and sanitized):

```
https://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}?
    X-Amz-Expires=900
    &X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
    &X-Amz-Credential={access key}/20150626/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
    &X-Amz-Date=20150626T195148Z
    &X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
    &X-Amz-Signature={signature}
```

What am I doing wrong that my pre-signed URLs are not being generated properly for downloading `aws:kms` encrypted files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, after much digging I found where I went wrong. To use `SignatureVersion4`, you need to set that *before* the client is created via a static property on the `AWSConfigs.S3Config` object. All the other fields I set are not needed in my case either.

Thus the proper way to do it is:

```
 private static AmazonS3Client CreateClient()
 {
     AWSConfigs.S3Config.UseSignatureVersion4 = true;
     return new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
 }
```

And creating the request

```
 var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
 {
     BucketName = bucket,
     Key = key,
     Expires = expires
 };
```